# inequality of absolute value problem

Tags: inequality

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ and $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ be real numbers taken at random, and $\alpha\gt0$. Show that:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n |X_kA_k| \le \frac{1}{\alpha}\sum_{i=1}^n X_k^2 + \frac{\alpha}{4}\sum_{k=1}^n A_k^2$$

Comment: Show your attempts.

Comment: I used inequality |a|<b, then -b<a<b. I've been making attempts from that, but I can't solve the problem. I don't know if it requires another theorem. Can you give me some advice?

Comment: You should add your attempts into the question body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We apply [AM-GM Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), then [Cauchy-Schwarz (CS) Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\alpha}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k^2 + \frac{\alpha}{4}\sum_{k=1}^n A_k^2 &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2}{\alpha}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k^2 + \frac{\alpha}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n A_k^2\right) \\
&\underbrace{\geq}_\text{AM-GM} \left[\left(\frac{2}{\alpha}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k^2\right)\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n A_k^2\right)\right]^\frac{1}{2} \\
&= \left(\sum_{k=1}^n X_k^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n A_k^2\right)^\frac{1}{2} \\
&\underbrace{\geq}_\text{CS} \sum_{k=1}^n |X_kA_k|
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot. You just gave me another idea to prove the problem. I will put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is my demonstration correct?

$$ (\frac{\sqrt1}{\sqrt\alpha}\sum_{i=1}^n X_k  + \frac{\sqrt\alpha}{\sqrt16}\sum_{k=1}^n A_k)^2 \ge 0$$ then $$-\sum_{k=1}^n X_kA_k \le \frac{1}{\alpha}\sum_{i=1}^n X_k^2 + \frac{\alpha}{4}\sum_{k=1}^n A_k^2$$

and

$$ (\frac{\sqrt1}{\sqrt\alpha}\sum_{i=1}^n X_k  - \frac{\sqrt\alpha}{\sqrt16}\sum_{k=1}^n A_k)^2 \ge 0$$ then $$\sum_{k=1}^n X_kA_k \le \frac{1}{\alpha}\sum_{i=1}^n X_k^2 + \frac{\alpha}{4}\sum_{k=1}^n A_k^2$$

therefore

$$\sum_{k=1}^n |X_kA_k| \le \frac{1}{\alpha}\sum_{i=1}^n X_k^2 + \frac{\alpha}{4}\sum_{k=1}^n A_k^2$$

Comment: RRL, Martin R, jvdhooft, Cesareo, Lê Thành Đạt. Your help is appreciated